# Python - Considering the official definition Numpy should be a module

Tags: python, numpy

I'm studying Python as beginner, please just don't blast me.

I've just studied that a module in Python is a collection of classes and functions; a package, instead, is just a way to identify modules in directories and subdirectories. So, a package in Python should not contain any classes and functions, and NumPy should calle d "module". Am I correct ?

The fact is that official doc for NumPy says :

> NumPy is the fundamental package for scientific computing with Python

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you have a specific question, which usually involves some code, please provide a [mcve]. Otherwise, google may help you access a number of resources to help answer your question.

Comment: Im sorry. I found a lot a theoric questions and answes in this site in the past, and i thought you could help me...

Comment: But importing a package imports its modules, giving you access to those classes.  So it doesn't make sense to say a a package shouldn't contain classes or functions.

Comment: The "import" statement is usable only for packages ?

Answer (score 3):

NumPy is a package. A package is represented by the file `__init__.py`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np
<module 'numpy' from '.../site-packages/numpy/__init__.py'>
```

When you look into this file, which is pretty long, you will find a lot of imports:

```
from . import core
from .core import *
from . import compat
from . import lib
from .lib import *
```

Therefore, all the names imported directly into `__init__.py` are available at the package level:

```
>>> np.array
<function numpy.core.multiarray.array>
```

But as you can see the function `array` is actually located deep down in the package directory hierarchy. Since always typing `numpy.core.multiarray.array` is pretty tiresome, importing this function into `__init__.py` makes a lot of sense becaues now you can type `np.array` instead.

Answer (score 1):

These terms are often used quite vaguely, but in theory, yes - a module is a collection of classes and functions, while a package is a collection of (one or more) modules.  However there are very few cases where a package just contains a module and no supporting code - since any package may want to provide e.g. `__version__`, `__all__` etc, or with subpackages offer methods that provide helper functions relating to imports etc.

So `numpy` is definitely a package, since it includes several sub-packages (`doc`, `random`, `fft` etc). Of course, it is *also* a module since it has 'top-level' classes and functions (e.g. `numpy.array`).

Comment: When i write "numpy.array" im referring to numpy module or numpy class ?

Comment: `array` is a function in the numpy module. numpy isn't a class (and  only has 3 classes defined in `__init__.py` which are for exception handling etc).

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers make clear, numpy is technically a package (a directory of importable things), but in this case I think the sentence you cite is using the term in its other sense: A package is a thing you can install.  PyPI is the Python **Package** Index, and pip stands for Pip Installs **Packages**.  Both PyPI and pip can deal with things that are single-file modules.  Package in this case is the general term for anything installable into your Python environment.